# Partial Evaluation and Currying

Tags: programming-languages, recursion, functional-programming, sml, currying

I have begun to understand a few examples related to currying but I am still not comfortable with the concept of currying as I would like to be. I know that currying can be used to do partial evaluation but I am not sure how it would work in certain cases.

I know how it works in the example below:

```
fun funkyPlus x y = x*x+y;
```

so let's say we only pass an argument for x then it is equivalent to the following:

```
fun funkyPlus 3 = (fn x => fn y => x*x+y)3
```

which ends up returning

```
fn y => 9+y
```

Now, I am trying to apply this idea to the built in function `foldl`.

I know the code for it is:

```
fun foldl f b [] = b
   |foldl f b (h::t) = foldl f f(h,b) t.
```

My question is, what if we do not pass all the arguments to `foldl` (i.e. we only pass it the first argument which is the function `('a*'b->'b)`). In the first example I gave, it was fairly simple to see how the function works when only one of the arguments is passed to it. However, I am having trouble seeing how `foldl` would work when there is only one argument passed to it.

Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This does not mean what you think:

   ```
   fun funkyPlus 3 = (fn x => fn y => x*x*y)3
   ```

   It defines a function which takes an argument that must be 3, and which evaluates to its RHS if it is 3 and is undefined otherwise. What you mean to say is this: If we only provide an argument for x, we have the following:

   ```
   funkyPlus 3
   → (fn x => fn y => x*x+y) 3
   ```

   and so forth.
2. Secondly, there is an error in your `foldl`:

   ```
   fun foldl f b [] = b|foldl f b (h::t) = foldl f f(h,b) t;
                                                    ^^^^^
   Type clash: expression of type
     'a * 'b
   cannot have type
     'c list
   ```

   This is because `(h,b)` is parsed as the third argument to `foldl` and not as the argument to `f`. Parenthesize it:

   ```
   fun foldl f b [] = b|foldl f b (h::t) = foldl f (f(h,b)) t;
   > val ('a, 'b) foldl = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
   ```

Now, getting to your question, ML can tell us that an expression like `foldl add` would have type `int -> int list -> int`.

But in general, it may help to realize that function application is entirely mechanical. If we have these two definitions:

```
fun foldl f b [] = b
  | foldl f b (h::t) = foldl f (f(h,b)) t;
add (x,y) = x + y;
```

then `var example = foldl add` would be equivalent to this:

```
fun example b [] = b
  | example b (h::t) = example (h::t) (add(h,b)) t;
```

All that’s been done is that `add` has been substituted for `f` in the body of `foldl`, nothing more (although I have taken the liberty of replacing `foldl add` with `example` in the body).

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to turn your top-level set of equations for `foldl` into a lambda expression which uses case analysis, like so:

```
val rec foldl = fn f => fn b => fn lst => 
  case lst of [] => b
        | (h::t) => foldl f (f(h,b)) t
```

Now you can use the same logic as before. Taking as an example the function `fn (x, y) => x * y`, we can see that

```
val prod = foldl (fn (x, y) => x * y)
```

is equivalent to

```
val prod = (fn f => fn b => fn lst => 
  case lst of [] => b
        | (h::t) => foldl f (f(h,b)) t) (fn (x, y) => x * y)
```

which [beta-reduces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_reduction#Reduction) to

```
val prod = fn b => fn lst => 
  case lst of [] => b
        | (h::t) => foldl (fn (x, y) => x * y) ((fn (x, y) => x * y)(h,b)) t
```

which beta-reduces to

```
val prod = fn b => fn lst => 
  case lst of [] => b
        | (h::t) => foldl (fn (x, y) => x * y) (h * b) t
```

Now since we know from our first definition that `prod` is equivalent to `foldl (fn (x, y) => x * y)`, we can substitute it into its own definition:

```
val rec prod = fn b => fn lst => 
  case lst of [] => b
        | (h::t) => prod (h * b) t
```

We can then mentally convert this back to a function defined by equations if we like:

```
fun prod b [] = b
  | prod b (h::t) = prod (h * b) t
```

That's about what you'd expect, right?